# connect to tfs with different user by using tfs api

Tags: powershell, api, tfs

I am trying to run a shellscript program to connect tfs by using tfsapi service.

Jenkins run on logged user but i want to connect tfs with different user (not with windows logged user)

How can i add credential to my powershell code? I use UseDefaultCredentials but need to use different user to connect tfs. how can i do that?

```
$tfsServerURL = "https://test.tfs.siemens.net/test"
$BuildDefinition = "test.rgs.project"

$URL = "$($tfsServerURL)"
#Get ID of Builddefinition
$buildDefinitionID = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($URL + '/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=2.0&name=' + $BuildDefinition) -Method GET -UseDefaultCredentials).value.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use this official Rest API: [Definitions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get specific build definition with additional parameter `name`. And this API supports [Oauth2 authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops). However, OAuth 2.0 is not supported on Azure DevOps Server. So we need to use [PAT authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) with below least scope: `vso.build`.

[image]

Therefore, if you want to connect tfs with different user using this API, please provide their corresponding PAT, and then below script should work as expected.

```
$tfsServerURL = "https://test.tfs.siemens.net/test"
$BuildDefinition = "test.rgs.project"

$URL = "$($tfsServerURL)"

$connectionToken="PAT here"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"}

#Get ID of Builddefinition
$buildDefinitionID = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($URL + '/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.0&name=' + $BuildDefinition) -Method GET -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader).value[0].id

Write-host $buildDefinitionID
```